# GPG error and apt-secure(8) errors. Unsigned keys and no release file

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, desktop-environments, gnupg

I have followed multiple threads to solve mainly the key errors and the `apt-secure(8)` error.

For the key issue I have downloaded `y-ppa manage` but to my knowledge all it may have done is reduce the amount of GPG errors.

Going through threads have sent my number of errors on a rollercoaster, decreasing and increasing the number listed.

I have pasted exactly what comes after `sudo apt-get update`. These errors started coming up after I downloaded gnome and plasma to play around with, of which plasma is super buggy.

```
     Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
     Ign:2 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily InRelease                           
     Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
     Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
     Hit:5 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily Release                             
     Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
     Ign:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy InRelease                      
     Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
     Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/daniruiz/flat-remix/ubuntu xenial InRelease     
     Ign:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy Release                       
     Hit:11 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                  
     Hit:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                    
     Ign:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse amd64 Packages
     Ign:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse i386 Packages      
     Ign:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse all Packages       
     Ign:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse Translation-en_US  
     Ign:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse Translation-en     
     Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dawidd0811/neofetch/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
     Ign:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
     Ign:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons 
     Ign:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse amd64 Packages     
     Ign:22 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbuntu_16.04  InRelease
     Ign:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse i386 Packages      
     Ign:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse all Packages       
     Hit:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/djcj/vapoursynth/ubuntu xenial InRelease       
     Ign:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse Translation-en_US  
     Hit:25 http://deb.playonlinux.com trusty InRelease                             
     Ign:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse Translation-en     
     Ign:26 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  InRelease
     Ign:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
     Ign:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons 
     Ign:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse amd64 Packages     
     Hit:27 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbuntu_16.04  Release
     Hit:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu xenial InRelease
     Ign:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse i386 Packages      
     Ign:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse all Packages       
     Ign:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse Translation-en_US
     Hit:29 https://packagecloud.io/gyazo/gyazo-for-linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease
     Hit:30 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  Release
     Hit:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu xenial InRelease     
     Ign:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse Translation-en     
     Ign:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
     Get:32 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbuntu_16.04  Release.gpg [189 B]
     Ign:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons 
     Ign:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse amd64 Packages
     Hit:34 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu xenial InRelease
     Ign:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse i386 Packages
     Ign:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse all Packages       
     Ign:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse Translation-en_US  
     Ign:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse Translation-en
     Ign:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
     Ign:32 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbuntu_16.04  Release.gpg
     Ign:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
     Ign:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse amd64 Packages
     Ign:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse i386 Packages
     Ign:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse all Packages
     Ign:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse Translation-en_US
     Hit:35 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libretro/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
     Ign:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse Translation-en     
     Ign:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
     Ign:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons 
     Err:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse amd64 Packages
       404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
     Ign:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse i386 Packages
     Ign:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse all Packages
     Ign:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse Translation-en_US
     Ign:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse Translation-en
     Ign:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
     Hit:36 http://ppa.launchpad.net/me-davidsansome/clementine/ubuntu xenial InRelease
     Ign:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons 
     Hit:37 http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/daily/ubuntu xenial InRelease             
     Hit:38 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu xenial InRelease
     Hit:39 http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease              
     Hit:40 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
     Hit:41 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/indicator-kdeconnect/ubuntu xenial InRelease
     Hit:42 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu xenial InRelease
     Fetched 189 B in 3s (60 B/s)                       
     Reading package lists... Done
     W: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hardy Release' does not have a Release file.
     N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
     N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
     W: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.gpg: Signature by key 1A2E38D61775C3963A039A87E3757B8E0D988D6E uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
     W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1466769448
     W: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' is not signed.
     N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
     N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
     E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
     E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Edit*

```
     Ign:1 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily InRelease
     Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
     Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
     Hit:4 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily Release                             
     Ign:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
     Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease             
     Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
     Hit:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
     Hit:9 https://download.sublimetext.com apt/stable/ InRelease                   
     Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/daniruiz/flat-remix/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
     Hit:11 http://deb.playonlinux.com trusty InRelease                             
     Ign:13 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbuntu_16.04  InRelease
     Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dawidd0811/neofetch/ubuntu xenial InRelease
     Ign:15 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  InRelease
     Hit:17 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbuntu_16.04  Release
     Hit:18 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/xUbuntu_16.04  Release
     Get:20 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbuntu_16.04  Release.gpg [189 B]
     Hit:21 https://packagecloud.io/gyazo/gyazo-for-linux/ubuntu xenial InRelease
     Ign:20 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbuntu_16.04  Release.gpg
     Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/djcj/vapoursynth/ubuntu xenial InRelease
     Hit:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu xenial InRelease
     Hit:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu xenial InRelease     
     Hit:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kubuntu-ppa/backports/ubuntu xenial InRelease  
     Hit:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libretro/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease        
     Hit:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/me-davidsansome/clementine/ubuntu xenial InRelease
     Hit:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/moka/daily/ubuntu xenial InRelease             
     Hit:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu xenial InRelease
     Hit:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/numix/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease              
     Hit:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
     Hit:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/indicator-kdeconnect/ubuntu xenial InRelease
     Hit:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu xenial InRelease
     Fetched 189 B in 4s (47 B/s)  
     Reading package lists... Done
     W: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.gpg: Signature by key 1A2E38D61775C3963A039A87E3757B8E0D988D6E uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
     W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbuntu_16.04  Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1466769448
     W: The repository 'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbuntu_16.04  Release' is not signed.
     N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
     N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Any reason you keep _very_ old repositories on your `sources.list`? I see lots of sources for `hardy` which went EOL in 2013 and that's why you're getting errors!

Comment: So I've removed the hardy repository but I still have the other errors.

Comment: can you edit your answer and update it with the new errors?

Answer (score 0):

For my case after resolving

```
W: http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/colomboem/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.gpg: Signature by key 1A2E38D61775C3963A039A87E3757B8E0D988D6E uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

by removing the repository the rest fell into place. Reading another thread Dukto is related to this repository. I had installed it a month or two prior and issues only arose after installing the plasma DE so I'm not entirely sure what to say about this.